# Does cron cache aws creds?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I have a cron job doing database backups on EC2 everyday and pushing them to S3. That EC2 has appropriate instance profile linked to the role that has permissions to put objects into a specific bucket. Some time ago I accidentally changed the instance profile to the one that doesn't have any S3 permissions, but the backups were still being pushed everyday regardless. Hence, my question is whether cron process that's been running for over a year somehow cached that previous, correct aws role and kept using it. If so, how could I investigate?

Comment: No, `cron` does not cache that information. Are you sure there isn't another role configured on the EC2 server somehow, in `~/.aws/credentials` perhaps?

Comment: There is no other role that have permission to access that s3 bucket. This happened to all 6 nodes in the cluster so I'm sure it's reproducible, and I will try to reproduce it in my personal account if I don't get to the bottom of this in a few days.

Comment: Could the S3 bucket itself have more open permissions (via the bucket policy) than you expect? Allowing access without explicit IAM role permissions?